# WebView can't set text to textarea

Tags: android, textarea, android-webview

I'm working on an Android project with `webview`. Everything works fine but I can't set text to a textarea. I have a bunch of pages that have a memo-writing option. I'm loading the code for the memo to a page with jQuery:

```
$('#memoContainer').load("memo.html");
```

memo.html textarea:

```
<div class="sisalto">
<textarea id="memo" style="width: 100%"> </textarea>
</div>
```

The textarea works, I can write in it and I can get the contents and save it in Android with jQuery:

```
function save(){
var newContent = $('#memo').val();
AndroidFunction.saveFile(newContent);
}
```

I'm trying to get the saved contents and set it in the textarea:

```
var setMemo = $('#memo');
setMemo.innerText("DOESNT WORK");
setMemo.val('NOPE');
```

I've tried googling and browsing here for hours but can't seem to find anything useful. Many suggest the `.val('smth');` option but it just doesn't work.

The memo is loaded before trying to set the content and everything is OK in my opinion. What is the problem here and any idea on how can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 'complete' function callback

```
$('#memoContainer').load('memo.html', function() {
    var setMemo = $('#memo');
    setMemo.val('hello');
});
```

Are you enabling javascript with the WebView? You need this to enable javascript:

```
WebView webView = ...
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Be sure jQuery is correctly loaded, can you post your code?

Here a working example (need internet permission since it uses CDN to load jquery):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String html = "<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<textarea id=\"area\"></textarea>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js\"></script>\n" +
                "<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js\"></script>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
                "        $(document).ready(function() {\n" +
                "                var area = $('#area');\n" +
                "                area.val('Hello');\n" +
                "        });\n" +
                "</script>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView web = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled and jQuery is loaded properly from a local file. Like I said, everything works except setting the text in to the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was the load-function. It loads the memo.html and shows it on the page but the actual code isn't injected to the page. Hence I can't set text to the textarea because it isn't actually there.